# How can I open pipes with OO style?

Tags: perl, pipe

I rewrite my old code in new style, like below:

```
#old style
open(FD,"file");

#new style
$fh = IO::File->new("file","r");
```

Files are ok, but I don't know how to open pipes.

```
# read from pipes.
open(PIPE,"some_program |");

# write to pipes.
open(PIPE,"| some_program");
```

How to treat pipes in OO Style IO?

adding:
thanks Jonathan, it's fine.

```
# read from pipes.
$pipe = IO::Pipe->new;
$pipe->reader('some_program');
$data = <$pipe>;

# write from pipes.
$pipe = IO::Pipe->new;
$pipe->writer('some_program');
print $pipe "foo,bar,baz";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check out [IO::Pipe](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Pipe.html) and [FileHandle](http://perldoc.perl.org/FileHandle.html).